# Need help getting Location in Touch as Async Task (works in wp)

Tags: mvvmcross

I have the following method I am hoping someone can help me with; it uses MvvmCross IMvxLocationWatcher. Basically the idea is to get a MvxGeoLocation result from a method which would encapsulate the watcher.

```
    protected internal static async Task<MvxGeoLocation> GetCurrentLocationAsync()
    {
        const int timeoutInMs = 5000;
        return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            MvxGeoLocation result = null;

            // wait event
            var manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

            var locationWatcher = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxLocationWatcher>();
            locationWatcher.Start(new MvxLocationOptions {Accuracy = MvxLocationAccuracy.Coarse},
                // success
                location =>
                {
                    result = location;
                    manualResetEvent.Set();
                },
                // fail
                error =>
                {
                    result = null;
                    manualResetEvent.Set();
                });

            // all done
            manualResetEvent.WaitOne(timeoutInMs);

            locationWatcher.Stop();

            return result;
        });
    }
```

This code works as expected in WindowsPhone; ResetEvent holds the event which I have set from the result.

In MonoTouch (iOS), however, I get nothing, and reset event times out (without any timeout, it never returns).

By making the locationWatcher as global class variable and not stopping it, I can see that location result returns as soon as this method exists.

I guess there are couple of other things I can try; Thread.Sleep (which I kind of feel is ugly), and Locking (but I thought ResetEvent almost works the same way).

Or is this a thread issue and implementation of monoTouch? Any suggestions anyone?

Thanks in advance.

Rana

Comment: Good to see you got a result from @Stephen Cleary - the MonoTouch implementation should really have worked on a background thread (not sure what the problem is you saw), but I know that on MonoDroid you **must** call Start on the UI thread - it's a platform limitation.

Comment: Thanks Stuart for the heads up for MonoDroid; that's a shame though - in my implementation it's really a service job... oh well, can't win them all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the threading model of `IMvxLocationWatcher` implementations. But you may have better results (and definitely better performance) on the UI thread:

```
protected internal static Task<MvxGeoLocation> GetCurrentLocationAsync()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<MvxGeoLocation>();
    const int timeoutInMs = 5000;
    var locationWatcher = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxLocationWatcher>();
    locationWatcher.Start(new MvxLocationOptions {Accuracy = MvxLocationAccuracy.Coarse},
        // success
        location => tcs.TrySetResult(location),
        // fail
        error => tcs.TrySetException(error));
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks a lot; I completely had forgotten about TaskCompletionSource; your method worked perfectly. I did add locationWatcher.Stop() inside the success and error (just to be safe), and returned a correct error; brilliant; one quick thing: VS keeps existing my debug session if I try to view the result back from this method. Any idea why that might happen?

Comment: I've never experienced that problem. It sounds like that could be a VS bug, or (more likely) a problem with the Xamarin plugin if you're using that.

Comment: How would you use the timeoutInMs properly? I see it is an un-used variable in the above snippet